# How to get free ether

Tags: metamask, rinkeby

im a complete beginner in ethereum.i want to develop ethereum base project in my degree.but problem is rinkeby test network not show in metamask wallet.how to get free ether for demo project purpose

Answer (score 2):

- If you already turn up test networks by getting into setting ->
  Advanced -> Show test networks. You'll realize that we still don't
  have rinkeby test network.
- And in [Rinkeby block exploer](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) have noticed that:

> The Rinkeby test net explorer has been discontinued and set to
> read-only on October 5th, 2022. Please migrate your contracts and
> deploy new ones on Goerli or Sepolia.

So you can change to Goerli to start your development. And easily get test net ETH by going to [Alchemy goerli faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/).